# Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs' - React

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to create react app without using create-react-app. Its throwing this error. Even in package.json scripts it tried changing the webpack-dev-server to webpack serve but its not working

could someone please help me. thanks

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  }, 


Require stack:
- C:\Users\aksha\Projects\onit-react-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aksha\Projects\onit-react-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\aksha\\Projects\\onit-react-app\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! onit-react-app@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the onit-react-app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aksha.DESKTOP-8T3GO8B\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-24T01_41_09_251Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Might be problem in versions of your libraries. Please check out : https://cyishere.medium.com/error-cannot-find-module-webpack-cli-bin-config-yargs-6d704533062a

Answer (score 1):

Please update `webpack-cli` to **v4** and use `webpack serve` to run `webpack-dev-server`

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
```